# Running a scheduled command in AWS in only one random machine

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to run a script every week. Basically, it gets the list of EC2 machines that match a specific series of tags, pick one of them, take a memory snapshot and publish it to S3. As simple as that.

I am taking a look to System Manager but I do not see how to run something in only one random machine.

I did a test with a Lambda, but it fails if it takes more than 3 seconds. Taking a snapshot lasts a few seconds, it is around 150 Mb and then it has to be updated. Lambda does not seem to be an option.

I could use CodeBuild for this, but how do I schedule the build to run once per week?

Having my own EC2 instance up all the time for this is the less desirable option.

Comment: Due to the "random" requirement Lambda or some custom code somewhere is probably the only way. A lambda function can run for at least 15 minutes if you change the timeout, but I suspect that was increased recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general both Lambda and CodeBuild will work (it depends on how long does it take to take the snapshot) and what type of language you would decide to use.
Lambda should suffice, I would assume that you have a minor issue with your code somewhere.

Now, for scheduling the task itself you need to use [CloudWatch Rules (aka Amazon EventBridge)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html). There you can have both scheduled or event-based rules which will trigger your rule, and you set up your Lambda function or a CodeBuild project as a target.

Comment: In the end I used a script in good old Jenkins :( I use the aws-cli to get the oldest running instance for a given tag, and run in it the command to take the snapshot and upload it to S3. But your answer adds up. Actually I am going to use CloudWatch Rules for something else. Cheers.